# Doctrine 2 - How to update schema with new enum values?

Tags: doctrine-orm, enums, doctrine, dbal

Following Doctrine 2's enum [defining a type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-2-defining-a-type) guide, I have the following class:

```
class EnumStatusType extends EnumType
{
    protected $name   = 'enumStatusType';
    protected $values = [
        'active',
    ];
}
```

Now, using `vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:diff`, or `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update` or whichever you prefer, it successfully creates the column with the enum:

```
status ENUM(\'active\') COMMENT \'(DC2Type:enumStatusType)\' NOT NULL
```

Now, I wanted to add a second value, `inactive`. But after running `orm:validate-schema`, `orm:schema-tool:update` `migrations:diff`, none of them notices there is a new value.

How can I make it so that it detects this type of changes, so that a new migration can be made with `migrations:diff`?

PS: I'm using `ZF2`, with the `DoctrineORMModule`. Not that it should matter though.

Comment: It can be pretty cumbersome to update enum values in a mysql database. Read also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508860/1697459). Not sure if Doctrine 2 is handling this correctly. I will do some reading before I post an answer.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html)?

Comment: @Wilt yes, I read that answer before. I figured I could temporarily write a migration manually that would alter the column, but I guess it's not "temporarily" anymore :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the enum values list in each field comment option, using the [postGenerateSchema event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postgenerateschema):

```
class EnumListener
{
    public function postGenerateSchema(\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $columns = [];

        foreach ($eventArgs->getSchema()->getTables() as $table) {
            foreach ($table->getColumns() as $column) {
                if ($column->getType() instanceof EnumType) {
                    $columns[] = $column;
                }
            }
        }

        /** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column $column */
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $column->setComment(trim(sprintf('%s (%s)', $column->getComment(), implode(',', $column->getType()->getEnum()::toArray()))));
        }
    }
}
```

Works for the `orm:schema-tool:update` command, I suppose it's the same for `migrations:diff`