# Mariadb 10.4 Data truncated for column 'column_name' on insert but not on update

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table (mariadb 10.4) called p:

```html
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                                                                                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| id             | int(11)                                                                                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description    | text                                                                                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url            | text                                                                                   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| source         | enum('source_a','source_b','source_c','source_d','source_e')                           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I currently have a couple of million rows on this table with the sources a, b, c, and d. Just recently we applied a migration to add source_e and we started getting the error `ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'source' at row 1` when trying to inset a row with the source_e. The used command that yields the error is the following:

`` INSERT INTO p (description, url, `source`)  VALUES ('test', 'https://google.com.br', 'source_e'); ``

Insertions with any of the other sources are still working.

The behavior changes when editing a row that is already on the db, the error is not shown:

`` UPDATE `p` SET `source`='source_e' WHERE `id`='3'; ``
Yields:
`Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.001 sec)`

Is there a way to debug this scenario? I've tried changing the log level of the db to get a better insight on the problem (`SET GLOBAL log_warnings=3;`) but the error message did not change.

I also tried changing the `source_e` name to `source_e_`, the error persisted.

Btw, i did change the name of the fields to comply with company policies.

Comment: How did you add 'source_e' to the list of enum values in source?

Comment: ```"ALTER TABLE `p` CHANGE COLUMN source source ENUM('source_a', 'source_b', 'source_c', 'source_d', 'source_e')"```

Comment: When you say you changed the name of the fields do you mean you changed the enum values? If so, then you probably have existing rows that no longer match any of the new enum values.

Comment: No, what i meant was that the names of the fields that I wrote on the question are not the same as seen in the actual database. I did not run any query with the altered field names. I did keep the same name structure when altering the names ([a-z]+_[a-z]+). Besides if the problem was existing data, I would face an error when trying to alter the table, in stead of on insertions.

Comment: It sounds like you added the new enum values by adding the new value to the end of the list, which seems exactly right. I don't have any other ideas. I will add this link, which you've probably already seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501958/how-do-i-add-more-members-to-my-enum-type-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was my bad. We happen to have a trigger on insertions of this table that feeds a materialized view kind of table. All I had to do was add 'source_e' to the source field on the other table.