# ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql

Hello i am a student and not familiar with MySQL.
I am new in mysql and i need help!
I have a database and have some troubles inserting data into one table.
The table name is `makina`

```
 CREATE TABLE `makina` (
  `lloji` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vitprodhimi` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ngjyra` enum('bardhe','blu','kuqe','zeze') DEFAULT 'bardhe'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And for the column `ngjyra` i doesn't accept the value `red`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of `ENUM` data type, it accept only your specific  values.

Read more on [The ENUM Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)

If you want to accept more values you should `alter` your table : [How do I add more members to my ENUM-type column in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501958/how-do-i-add-more-members-to-my-enum-type-column-in-mysql)

```
ALTER TABLE
    `makina`
MODIFY COLUMN
    `ngjyra` enum(
        'existing_value1',
        'existing_value2',
        'existing_value3',
        'existing_value4',
        'new_value1',
        'new_value2'
    )
DEFAULT  `bardhe`;
```